# How to format a currency colum in Flask-Appbuilder?

Tags: python, flask

I have a model with a price column. Using `ModelView`, I want the price column to be right aligned with two decimal places and a currency symbol.  How do I change the format of the price column?

Answer (score 1):

upgrade flask-appbuilder to 1.4.4 and use the new @renders decorator to do this:

Custom Model properties can be used on lists. This is usefull for formating values like currencies, time or dates. or for custom HTML. This is very simple to do, first define your custom property on your Model and use the @renders decorator to tell the framework to map you class method with a certain Model property:

```
from flask.ext.appbuilder.models.decorators import renders

class MyModel(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique = True, nullable=False)
    custom = Column(Integer(20))

    @renders('custom')
    def my_custom(self):
        # will render this columns as bold on ListWidget
        return Markup('<b>' + custom + '</b>')
```

On your view reference your method as a column on list:

```
class MyModelView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(MyTable)
    list_columns = ['name', 'my_custom']
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response - deeply impressed.
I use <div> to get the alignment:
return Markup('<div align=right>&euro;' + s + '</div>')

Comment: Getting `NameError: name 'Markup' is not defined` any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include decorate-relevant code in model.py.
the following can be a good alternative.

```
class FormattedListWidget(ListWidget):
    template = 'widgets/my_list.html'

class MyModelView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(MyTable)
    list_widget = FormattedListWidget
    list_columns = ['my_dirthday']
    formatters_columns={'my_dirthday':lambda x:'<b>'+x.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')+'</b>'}
```

my_list.html is from ~/flask_appbuilder/templates/appbuilder/general/widgets/list.html

it must be located in your /templates/widgets directory.
and just edit my_list.html as following.

[before]

```
<td>{{ formatter(item[value])}}
```

[after editing]

```
<td>{{ formatter(item[value]) |safe }}
```

Comment: what's a dirthday?